# Can't set a default value on select>option when using ngChange="myFunction()" in my angular app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-ng-change, angularjs-select

I'm building an angular app ; and I have to set a default value coming from `$scope.ecole.niveauid` of my controller.
To do so, I just wrote this code :

```
<select class="form-control" name="niveau">
      <option value="{[{niveau.id}]}"
              ng-repeat="niveau in niveaux"
              ng-selected="niveau.id == ecole.niveauid">
              {[{niveau.libelle}]}
      </option>
 </select>
```

And it works really great.

Now I need to retrieve the selected value and pass it to a function of my controller.
So I added :

```
<select class="form-control"
          ng-model="niveau"
          ng-change="reload(niveau)">

          <option value="{[{niveau.id}]}"
                  ng-repeat="niveau in niveaux"
                  ng-selected="niveau.id == ecole.niveauid">
                  {[{niveau.libelle}]}</option>
</select>
```

In my controller, I've :

```
 $scope.reload = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
    }

  $scope.niveaux = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "libelle": "level1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "libelle": "level2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "libelle": "level3"
        }];
 $scope.ecole.niveauid = 3;
```

Everything work, but I don't have my default value anymore.
Please how can I set a default value and retrieved the changed value based on $scope controller ?

Comment: what you have in reload function ?

Comment: What is ecole.niveauid in ng-selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a selected value object on your controller's scope and set id property on this object after niveaux is set.

```
$scope.niveaux = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "libelle": "level1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "libelle": "level2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "libelle": "level3"
    }];

$scope.selectedValue = {id: "2"};  //selected value onload (pass your selected value here)

$scope.reload = function (){
    var selectedId = $scope.selectedValue.id;
    //do something
}
```

Then in your HTML, you just need to update your binding. You don't need to specify the ng-selected anymore since it will automatically bind ng-model with option value `value="{[{niveau.id}]}"`. You just need to set the selected property once after loading niveaux list.

```
<select class="form-control"
          ng-model="selectedValue.id"
          ng-change="reload()">

          <option value="{[{niveau.id}]}"
                  ng-repeat="niveau in niveaux">
                  {[{niveau.libelle}]}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes thank you, it works great. But I changed the `$scope.selectedValue = {id: "2"}` to `$scope.selectedValue = {id: $scope.ecole.niveauid.toString()}` because I want that value to be based on a scope. Thx again

Comment: Yes that's perfect! I didn't knew the exact path `$scope.ecole.niveauid.toString()` so i hard coded this with the comment, glad it worked! :)